# How to retain Scikit-learn OneHotEncoding from model generation to use on new data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm using `OneHotEncoding` to generate dummies for a classification problem. When used on the training data, I get ~300 dummy columns, which is fine. However, when I input new data (which is fewer rows), the `OneHotEncoding` only generates ~250 dummies, which isn't surprising considering the smaller dataset, but then I can't use the new data with the model because the features don't align.

Is there a way to retain the `OneHotEncoding` schema to use on new incoming data?

Comment: where is your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using `fit_transform` on both training and test dataset, which is not the right approach because the encoding schema has to be consistent on both the dataset for the model to understand the information from the features.

The correct way is do

- `fit_transform` on training data
- `transform` on test data

By doing this way, you will get consistent number of columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is a much better formed question for anyone who comes across this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152282/saving-a-feature-vector-for-new-data-in-scikit-learn?rq=1)